# Select Into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table Like

OldTbl

```
ID   Name  Age
12   name1  15
544  name2  15
2544 name3  15
```

I need to make th ID like this using query  (ID is primary key)

```
ID   Name  Age
1    name1  15
2    name2  15
3    name3  15
```

Any Ideas ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a query:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as id, name, age
from table t;
```

If you want to update the table, then do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select row_number() over (order by id) as new_id, t.*
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id;
```

Comment: Could I use it in select insert command like 
   INSERT INTO NewTbl
   (ID
    ,Name
    ,Age)
   select
        ID
    ,Name
    ,Age
     FROM OldTbl

Comment: Yes, you could put an `insert` before the first query.